# Problem while setting private ethereum network on AWS using bootnode

Tags: private-blockchain, bootnodes

I'm trying to set up a private ethereum network using bootnode. I created two instances on EC2 (t2.medium) having the same security group.Firstly i created boot key by using

```
 bootnode -genkey boot.key
```

then i set up the bootnode by using following command

```
 bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 7 -addr "172.31.20.13:30310"
```

The bootnode was set up successfully with enode value =enode://52c75d5bb8f8287a5942151dabb35756b2ee664faa8a1f98b8fb5ae778953bf0dde553b0d574e85cbfcbd8adf4068a0c7611f270e673776c7e67225b38eadcd2@172.31.20.13:30310

I initialised both the nodes using the genesis file and following command

```
geth --datadir "./mydatadir" init genesis.json
```

Genesis.json

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 1337,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0
},
"nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
"timestamp": "0x00",
"parentHash":      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"extraData": "0x00",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",
"difficulty": "0x01",
"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x238dd521ad221b37cc176fa9f4bf88cf19fe39f1",
"alloc": {
 "0x238dd521ad221b37cc176fa9f4bf88cf19fe39f1" : {
 "balance" : "200000000000000000000000"
 },
 "0xaebc7588345fc7963505dd6de9d12390980fc13d" : {
 "balance" : "10000000000000000000"
 },
"0xa5c77bd6319a5eaba9494acd90cac9712f9e15c9" : {
 "balance" : "20000000000000000000"
}
}
}
```

I tried connecting now two nodes (two instances) to bootnode one node being on the same instance that of bootnode. I used th following command

```
geth --networkid 1337 --datadir "./mydatadir" --bootnodes                              "enode://52c75d5bb8f8287a5942151dabb35756b2ee664faa8a1f98b8fb5ae778953bf0dde553b0d574e85cbfcbd8adf4068a0c7611f270e673776c7e67225b38eadcd2@172.31.20.13:30310" --port 3003 --ipcdisable --syncmode full console
```

This nodes gets joined to bootnode successfully interacting with it

```
TRACE[05-24|21:01:55] << FINDNODE/v4                           addr=172.31.20.13:3003 err="unknown node"<br>
TRACE[05-24|21:01:55] >> PONG/v4                               addr=172.31.20.13:3003 err=nil<br>
TRACE[05-24|21:01:55] << PING/v4                               addr=172.31.20.13:3003 err=nil<br>
TRACE[05-24|21:01:55] Starting bonding ping/pong               id=33c0695b8d4f9ff6 known=false failcount=0 age=424221h1m55.666391609s<br>
TRACE[05-24|21:01:55] >> PING/v4                               addr=172.31.20.13:3003 err=nil
```

But when i run the same command on other instance (node)

```
geth --networkid 1337 --datadir "./mydatadir" --bootnodes "enode://52c75d5bb8f8287a5942151dabb35756b2ee664faa8a1f98b8fb5ae778953bf0dde553b0d574e85cbfcbd8adf4068a0c7611f270e673776c7e67225b38eadcd2@172.31.20.13:30310" --port 3004 --ipcdisable --syncmode full console
```

The node is launched successfully but i don't see it interacting with the bootnode and when i type admin.peer command on both the nodes i get empty list.Am i doing something wrong? Please help me out

Comment: my bad i got it working had issues with security groups on aws 
ps: I'm new to aws

Answer (score 0):

you also have to enable UPD rule for

> 30310 upd rule in security group

for ec2 instance running bootnode.