# Private Ethereum Cluster showing ENR Errors

Tags: geth-debugging

I am trying to run a 3 node cluster, 1 among three is miner. When I try to make  sendTransation its seems be signed but seems to halt forever with message signed and must wait for others.

[image: Signed recently must wait for others]

The logs also show ENR request failed which doesnt seems okay:

[image]

Other details, I have a bootnode which serves at peer discovery node. My nodes runes with command

```
geth --nousb --bootnodes "enode://$bootnodeId@$bootnodeIp:30301"  \
--rpc  --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"   --networkid "15" --verbosity 5 --maxpeers 3  \
 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,miner,debug,personal,rpc" --syncmode full
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable UDP rule for port 30310 for ec2 instance running bootnode.

[Problem while setting private ethereum network on AWS using bootnode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49489/problem-while-setting-private-ethereum-network-on-aws-using-bootnode)