# Bootnode connection error

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, bootnodes

i am trying to create private POA network in which i have 3 aws ec2 ubuntu servers.
on 1st server bootnode and on 2nd server POA node1 is running and on 3rd server POA node 2 running.
but i am not able to connect the node1 and node2 also bootnode shows this error when i tried to just node2 to connect to

> DEBUG[09-17|02:27:35.307] ENR request failed                       id=7498feef0de4a2e6 addr=@ip:30312 err="invalid IP in response record: loopback address from non-loopback host"

Comment: I think, any of the deployed geth nodes is using non-loopback address and other one is using loopback address. When bootnode gets a request of findNode and handles it, it finds that one is loopback and another one is non. So, it gives the error response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable UDP rule for port 30310 for ec2 instance running bootnode.

[Problem while setting private ethereum network on AWS using bootnode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49489/problem-while-setting-private-ethereum-network-on-aws-using-bootnode)

Comment: thanks in advance!! let me check and get back to you..

Comment: i just realise when i use  **bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr :30310** command to setup bootnode it gives                 self=enode://somenode@127.0.0.1:30310 .. that 127.0.0.1 is problem i guess. also i tried using **bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr 0.0.0.0:30310** still 127.0.0.1 remains same